# Excel2013 - Leaving cell blank when there is no time value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am summing time values (seconds and minutes) but I am having trouble in finding the right formula to leave a cell blank if there is no time in a cell, meaning: Don't do any sum just leave the cell blank.

[image: EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 0):

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="","",SUM($A$2:A2))
```

apply proper formatting and copy downward:

[image]

Note:

**B5** will remain blank until **A5** is filled in.

**EDIT#1:**

Depending on the **language** Excel is using, you may need to:

- change the spelling of the `SUM()` function
- use a **;** in place of the **,**

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks a lot for you help, my Excel is not accepting the formula. Don't know why. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hj16.jpg

Comment: @MichelSantos  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @MichelSantos, your  Formula should be written like `=IF(D7="", "",SUM($D$7:D7))`. in fact you have used `"""` instead of `""` !

Comment: Hi Rajesh... true that the pic shows a bad formula but I was trying to try every way and i forgot to erase the extra " .. I did the one it was sugested but it still gives error. What a headache. I suspect that it could be my excel version... I really appreciate your help  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAZZj.jpg